# Corrigir arquivos não rastreados ou deletados no repositório clonado

Tags: git

Clonei o ramo de um projeto, ao concluir surgiu alguns arquivos não acompanhados pelo git e alguns com alterações.

Exemplos:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    "index.htm"
        deleted:    "img/del/mix.jpg"

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        "front/sobre.html"
        "back/login.jsp"
```

Fiz algumas tentativas sem sucesso para cancelar.

git checkout --

> error: pathspec 'index.htm' did not match any file(s) known to git.

git co -f

> Already on 'ramo'
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/ramo'.

git reset --hard HEAD~1

> Checking out files: 100% (58/58), done. HEAD is now at abcd123 Merge
>
> branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/projeto
>
> into ramo

Obs: Manteve as alterações.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer desfazer essas mudanças faça o seguinte:

```
git checkout index.htm img/del/mix.jpg
```

vai "restaurar" esses dois arquivos, ou seja vai ficar igual quando você clonou o repo

Os arquivos:

```
    "front/sobre.html"
    "back/login.jsp"
```

Pode deletar manualmente, pois são arquivos que não estão sendo gerenciados pelo git